# moving a working filter to return roles as per my scope dynamically in the model

Tags: laravel, scope

### My tasks model has one user

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id' );
}
```

### And my user Model has many roles (manyToMany)

```
public function hasRole($role) {
    if($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) return true;
    return false;
}
```

### Which works in my task controller:

```
$tasks = Task::all();

$tasks = $tasks->filter(function($task)
{
 return $task->user->hasRole('admin');
});
```

Here I get all tasks which have a admin role = OK

When I want to use a dynamic scope in my model for this, I have to use the query builder where I need to return the same.

In my controller I want to do something like:

```
$tasks = Task::filterRoles('admin')->get();
```

And in my model

```
public function scopeFilterRoles($query, $type )
{
    // use $type to filter $query so only tasks->user->hasRole($type) are returned 

... ??? 

        return $tasks;
}
```

which I can't get to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Task model define method

```
public function scopeFilterRoles($query, $role)
{
    return $query->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($role) {
        $q->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($role) {
            $q->where('name', $role);
        });
    });
}
```

Usage

`Task::filterRoles('admin')->get();`

Also you can change User class method this way

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    return $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->exists();
}
```

Comment: Great! this works. Thanks, this could help many. Could you also have a solution for  $q->where('name', '!=', $role); ? (does not work)

Comment: It would be interesting to know why my question get negative feedback.

Comment: Changing $q->whereHas('roles', ... to $q->whereDoesntHave('roles', ...  answers my first comment. Thanks